# Would you use fluent validation with database calls

Tags: c#, database, fluentvalidation

With fluent validation you can validate simple things such as NotNull , numberGreaterThan or more advance business rules such as userMustExistsOnDb before updating his password.

I am feeling that **when I use fluent validation I do double number of DB calls than when I am not** using it. Here is an example.

```
public class DeleteCustomerRequestValidator: AbstractValidator<DeleteCustomerRequest> {
  public DeleteCUstomerRequestValidator() {
    RuleFor(customer => customer.Id).GreaterThan(0);
    RuleFor(customer => customer.Id).Must(ExistsOnDB).WithMessage("The customer does not exists");
  }

  private bool ExistsOnDB(int customerId) {
    // DB call to check if exists on Db
    return Respository.Customers.Any(x => x.Id == customerId)    // CALL NUMBER 1
  }
}
```

Here is the delete method where I do the second call

```
public void DeleteCustomer(int customerId)
{
     Customer customer = Repository.Customers.First(x => x.Id);  // CALL NUMBER 2
     Repository.Customers.Delete(customer) 
     Repository.Save()
}
```

However If I would no use Fluent validation I would be doing **only one call** to get the customer from DB.

```
public void DeleteCustomer(int customerId)
{
     if (customerId < 1)
     {
         /// Return error.
     }
     Customer customer = Repository.Customers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id);  // Only 1 CALL
     if (customer == null)
     {
         // Return error.
     }
     Repository.Customers.Delete(customer) 
     Repository.Save()
}
```

What I am doing wrong? Is there a better way of doing it?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Open up SQL Server profiler and see what calls are hitting the db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, I would say NO, don't use Fluent Validation.

1. I think you are adding extra complexity / un-necessary AbstractValidator classes, where a simple if would have sufficed.
2. For something like "Delete", yes you will be checking if the customer exist first. But MOST logic should be in the Customer class itself. Therefore, you should not need this external validator class.

Comment: Although I can understand this answer for simple case of validation. There are cases where there are many validations and then you might end in dividing the validation logic in multiple places. I think that a better approach will be to send the result of the db query as a [validation context](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/advanced.html#root-context-data). A better approach will simply be to cache the result and then you don't really care from multiple calls as long as they are in the boundaries of the cache expiry time

Answer (score 0):

You need FluidValidation if you want to have a single IsValid and a list of errors that occurred during a process. In this case you would add a validation that the whole deletion succeeded and if not, the validation would record why not. But not a validation for each line of code.